# Cannot Find property after adding it with hook_entity_property_info_alter (callback not firing)

Tags: nodes, entities

I'm very new to drupal, so forgive me if this is a simple question, but I have been working on this for a few days and have not yet found a solution.

I have an entity, to which I've added the property "hour_created" via the `hook_entity_property_info_alter()` function. The property has a getter_callback function that simply returns an integer for now. I can see that this property has been added by calling `watchdog("normal", print_r($info, true))` after adding the property in the same `hook_entity_property_info_alter()` function.

The problem is that it does not appear this property is ever actual added to the entity when I try to look at it through Drupal. I added a `watchdog("normal", print_r($item, true));` call in the callback, but the watchdog is never called, and never appears in the logs. To try and get the callback to fire, I have tried the following:

1. node-load through drush
2. loading the node through the site directly
3. directly attempting to access the property with php

Unfortunately, I have had no success with any of my above attempts. I suppose what we can boil this question down to is 'How can I make my entity property getter_callback fire, and why isn't it fired when I load the node?' I apologize if any of this is a little muddled, please let me know if any of this is unclear or if you need more information.

Thanks!

**EDIT:**
Here's the code for my callback:

```
function mymodule_test_property_getter_callback($item) {
  watchdog("normal", print_r($item, true));
  return 10;
}
```

And here's my `hook_entity_property_info_alter()` function:

```
function mymodule_entity_property_info_alter(&$info) {
  $info['node']['bundles']['mynode']['properties']['test_property'] = array(
    'label' => t('Just a test!'),
    'type' => 'integer',
    'computed' => TRUE,
    'required' => TRUE,
    'getter callback' => 'mymodule_test_property_getter_callback'
  );
  watchdog("normal", print_r($info, true));
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers :) Could you post your code from `hook_entity_info_alter()` and the getter callback (you can edit it into the question rather than list it in the comments)? I can't recall ever seeing anything in core that would let you add properties to an entity through `hook_entity_info_alter()`, are you using the extensions provided by Entity API or ECK? If so, do they definitely support adding properties?

Comment: @Clive sorry! I am using `hook_entity_property_info_alter` not `hook_entity_info_alter`. I fixed this is in the question, and also added the code both the functions. And ps: thanks! glad to be here!

Comment: No worries, thanks for adding the code in. I _think_ (not 100% sure) you can only use `hook_entity_property_info_alter()` to alter existing properties, not to add new ones. But I might be wrong, entity is a great module. Just off to try it out, if I come up with anything I'll let you know

Comment: Hm...I think you can use it to add properties, too. This is the page I was looking at while doing this, and he seems to use the approach I did as far as I can tell: http://ygerasimov.com/add-custom-field-search-api-apachesolr-index

Comment: I stand corrected :)

Comment: It confused me too when I saw it ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is what's going on...

With your current code you've described the property to the entity API module; if you want to access it via that you already can:

```
$node = node_load($nid);
$wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $node);
print $wrapper->test_property->value(); // Prints '10'
```

But the core entity system has no knowledge of `test_property`, so it doesn't show up on a node object from `node_load()`. To get it there, you'll need to implement [`hook_node_load()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_load/7):

```
function mymodule_node_load($nodes, $types) {
  foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    if ($type == 'mynode') {
      $node->test_property = mymodule_test_property_getter_callback($node);
    }
  }
}
```

There's also the outside chance that your getter callback will rely on something having been added to the node object already, by another module's implementation of `hook_node_load()`. You can get past that by moving your implementation to last in the queue, with [`hook_module_implements_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_module_implements_alter/7).

If you want Views support, I think you'll also need to implement [`hook_views_data_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_data_alter/7) to add the property to the `node` table. But maybe the entity module will magic that up for you, it's a good'un.

Comment: Agreed! Thanks for taking the time to explain it, and not just giving me the code. You have taught me to fish, and I will not be hungry

Answer (score 0):

Answer suggested by Clive works perfect. For views integration 'entity views field' => TRUE, has to added, for example

```
    function mymodule_entity_property_info_alter(&$info) {
      $info['node']['bundles']['mynode']['properties']['test_property'] = array(
        'label' => t('Just a test!'),
        'type' => 'integer',
        'computed' => TRUE,
        'required' => TRUE,
        'getter callback' => 'mymodule_test_property_getter_callback',
         'entity views field' => TRUE,
    );
    watchdog("normal", print_r($info, true));
    }
```

Comment: If this is meant to be an answer, please make it complete one. It's OK to mention other people answers, but your answer should make sense even if all others are deleted.