# How to make custom entity properties available on entity_load?

Tags: 7, entities

I am altering another entity by adding some more (read only) properties to it.

```
<?php
hook_entity_property_info_alter(&$info) {
  $info['entity']['properties']['entity_edit_url'] = array(
    'label' => t("Edit URL"),
    'description' => t("The edit URL of the entity."),
    'getter callback' => 'entity_get_custom_properties',
    'type' => 'uri',
    'computed' => TRUE,
  );
  ...
}
?>
```

These properties are working fine in rules and entity metadata wrappers, but on entity load they are not present. This is tested with:

```
<?php
$e = entity_load('entity_type', array(1));
dpm($e);

// Expected 
$e->entity_edit_url = 'something';
?>
```

I could use hook_entity_load to fetch these properties from the database on load, but that feels like an ugly workaround:

```
<?php
function hook_entity_load($entities, $type) {
  if($type == 'my_entity') {
    foreach ($entities as &$entity) {    
      list($id) = entity_extract_ids($type, $entity);

      $entity->entity_edit_url = 'user/' . $entity->uid . '/entity/' . $id . '/edit';
    }
  }
}
?>
```

I can't figure out why it does work in rules. Am I loading the entity in a wrong way, or is there a trick to attach these additional properties to the entity? I already provided a getter callback for fetching these properties, so doing it again in hook_entity_load feels wrong.

Comment: And the answer is given here: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/96133/cannot-find-property-after-adding-it-with-hook-entity-property-info-alter-callb It should be set in `hook_entity_load` or read using the contrib Entity API.